# Haskell - tree with two variables in each node

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm trying to define a tree, which has two values in each node. One represents value of the node and second means distance from a leaf.

```
data Tree2 a b = Nil 0  | T (Tree2 a b) (a b) (Tree2 a b) deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)
```

Is the definition correct? Does "Nil 0" make sense? I am trying to say that, if the value isn't in a tree than the distance is 0.

Comment: By `(a b)` did you mean to write `(a,b)` or `a b`? Because `(a b)` defines a single parameter where `b` is a type parameter of `a`

Comment: I wanted to define two parameters

Comment: Requiring two parameters seems unnecessary. You could just define a tree that takes one parameter, where the value is a tuple of two values.

Comment: Can you write down here an example? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Think at the Nil tree as a way to say "stop here, there is no more leaves", so there is no need to add data there, you can only say:

```
data Tree2 a b = Nil | T (Tree2 a Int) a Int (Tree2 a Int)
```

And calculates the distance in the right side each time a node is created.

```
getDistance :: Tree2 a Int -> Int
getDistance Nil              = 0
getDistance (T _ _ n _) = n
```

Comment: I thought that you wanted to calculate the distance, so I thought if you add it there, each time you add a node (if you create the function) you can auto calculate the distance, and when you want it, just get the value

Comment: Yes, I just wondered, why exactly in right subtree, but now it makes much more sense :]

Comment: Yes of course, I'm glad to helped you, your question was interesting. can I know why are you using that data structure for?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to write a program, which accepts as input a tree and program has to output a sorted list by distances from leaves.

Comment: Cool, I think you are in the right way, the b parameter what's for?

Comment: First program accept a tree. Then convert it to tree with values and distances and then I put it in to the list

Comment: Well, I thought that b parameter would be for a distance. But your solution pass the distance to Int. So I will a little bit modify your solution

Comment: When you finish edit my answer so it will maybe help others! Thank you

Comment: @DamianLattenero Generally people aren't aloud to make substantial edits to other peoples' posts which put words in others' mouth. Edits can change the format and wording of posts, but not the meaning. If you want your post to be a community effort and not your own, you should make your post a community wiki. Otherwise people should write their own answers if they want to make a meaningful addition.

Comment: @chi yes! you are totally right! my wrong! Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

Defining a tree that contains two values at each node is unnecessary, because you could just use a tree that contains one value at each node, but it consists of a tuple of two values.

For example:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

type Tree2 a b = Tree (a,b)
```

Now you've got a `Tree2` that possesses all of the characteristics of `Tree`, but requires 2 type parameters.

An example of a function using it would be:

```
getDistance :: (Num b) => Tree2 a b -> b
getDistance Nil              = 0
getDistance (Node _ (_,x) _) = x
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it compile blindly I would write it this way:

```
data Tree2 a b = Nil | T (Tree2 a b) (Tree2 a b)
```

this one :

```
Nil 0
```

does not make sense for me.

so I would re-write it this way:

```
data Tree2 a = Nil | T a (Tree2 a) (Tree2 a)
```

If you really want to store two types a and b in your node: it becomes

```
data Tree2 a b = Nil | T a b (Tree2 a b) (Tree2 a b)
```

But your notation

```
(a b)
```

may not mean what you thought it mean. As the comment below remarks, in `(a b)` the `a` would be understood as a kind * -> * ( you can understand this like a type which expects another type.

Give `a` being `[]` , and `b` being `Int`, `(a b)` would be understood as `[Int]`. Given `a` being `Maybe`, and `b` being `String`, `(a b)` would be understodd as `Maybe String`.
And that would be the node value stored in your tree structure.

Comment: Actually, I think that probably *would* work. `a` would have to be instantiated to a type of kind `* -> *`, which could be various useful things like `(,) Int`, Identity, `Maybe`, etc.

Comment: Are you sure for the tuple (,), is it not of kind * -> * -> * ?

Comment: It is, but I wrote it partially applied to `Int`.